How to publish Mend CLI scan reports for Docker images to Mend?
I have been able to produce a SARIF scan report for a Docker image using the Mend CLI and I was also able to publish it to Github Advanced Security. I was under the impression that this Mend CLI would also be able to publish the results to Mend, but I can't see how exactly.
My user has product admin privileges.
I have the following Github workflow:
name: Publish Docker image

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      image_name:
        description: 'Docker image name'
        default: ${{ github.event.repository.name }}
        type: string
      tag:
        description: 'Release tag version'
        required: true
        type: string
      tag_latest:
        description: 'Tag as latest version?'
        default: true
        required: false
        type: boolean
      tag_minimal:
        default: ""
        description: 'Minimal supported tag version'
        required: false
        type: string

env:
  REGISTRY: docker.foo.corp

permissions:
  actions: write
  contents: write
  security-events: write

jobs:
  tag:
    name: Tag & Release
    runs-on: [self-hosted, myrunners]
    container:
      image: mydockerimg.foo.corp/ci-base:1.0.4
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Set Git Config
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "someuser@foo.corp"
          git config --local user.name someuser"

      - name: Tag latest commit
        run: git tag ${{ inputs.tag }}

      - name: Push changes
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          branch: ${{ github.ref }}
          tags: true

  publish-image:
    name: Publish Image
    runs-on: [self-hosted, myrunner]
    needs: tag
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      # Uses the `docker/login-action` action to log in to the Container registry using the account and password that
      # will publish the packages. Once published, the packages are scoped to the account defined here.
      - name: Log in to the Container registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3

      - name: Add certificate to the builder
        run: |
          BUILDX_CONTAINER_ID=$(docker ps -aqf "name=${{ steps.setup-buildx-action.outputs.name }}")
          docker cp /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/some.crt $BUILDX_CONTAINER_ID:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates
          docker exec $BUILDX_CONTAINER_ID update-ca-certificates

      # This step uses [docker/metadata-action](https://github.com/docker/metadata-action#about) to extract tags and
      # labels that will be applied to the specified image. The `id` "meta" allows the output of this step to be
      # referenced in a subsequent step. The `images` value provides the base name for the tags and labels.
      - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels)
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v5
        with:
          images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ inputs.image_name }}
          tags: type=raw,value=${{ inputs.tag }}

      # This step uses the `docker/build-push-action` action to build the image, based on your repository's
      # `Dockerfile`. If the build succeeds, it pushes the image to GitHub Packages.
      # It uses the `context` parameter to define the build's context as the set of files located in the specified path.
      # For more information, see "[Usage](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action#usage)" in the README of the
      # `docker/build-push-action` repository.
      # It uses the `tags` and `labels` parameters to tag and label the image with the output from the "meta" step.
      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          cache-from: type=gha
          cache-to: type=gha,mode=max
          context: .
          file: ./Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: |
            ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
            ${{ inputs.tag_latest == true && format('{0}/{1}:latest', env.REGISTRY, inputs.image_name) || '' }}
            ${{ inputs.tag_minimal != '' && format('{0}/{1}:{2}', env.REGISTRY, inputs.image_name, inputs.tag_minimal)|| '' }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
          platforms: linux/amd64
          build-args: |
            BUILDTIME=${{ fromJSON(steps.meta.outputs.json).labels['org.opencontainers.image.created'] }}
            VERSION=${{ fromJSON(steps.meta.outputs.json).labels['org.opencontainers.image.version'] }}
            REVISION=${{ fromJSON(steps.meta.outputs.json).labels['org.opencontainers.image.revision'] }}

      - name: Download Mend CLI & Run a Scan
        run: |
          export MEND_URL=${{ secrets.MEND_URL }}
          export MEND_ORGANIZATION=${{ secrets.MEND_ORGANIZATION }}
          export MEND_USER_KEY=${{ secrets.MEND_USER_KEY }}
          export MEND_EMAIL=${{ secrets.MEND_EMAIL }}
          
          curl https://downloads.mend.io/cli/linux_amd64/mend -o /tmp/mend && chmod +x /tmp/mend
          
          /tmp/mend auth info --non-interactive
          /tmp/mend image ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ inputs.image_name }}:${{ inputs.tag }} --format sarif --filename results.sarif --local-pull

      - name: Upload sarif
        uses: github/codeql-action/upload-sarif@v2
        with:
          sarif_file: results.sarif


I have been reading through the documentation, but the Github integration seems to not be very well documented in this regard.
What do I need to execute now in order to publish this to Mend?
Is there a Github action that can be used to check pull requests and add comments with findings like such exist for Checkmarx One, for example?

The Mend API doesn't seem to have an endpoint to update (or event create / post) reports. I'm not familiar with the terms used by this security tool, but if there is one of those endpoint that could enable that operation, creating a github action to do should not be that difficult.

The Mend Legacy API did have some endpoints related to Reports, but they were just getting information, none of them allow to update or create reports.

The thing is that the documentation states that you need to use --update/-u with --file because by default the CLI doesn't upload the scans for Docker images. However, this does not seem to work if I append it to my command line above. Has anyone gotten it to work?

From what I've seen, currently only organization-level admins can upload Docker image scan results to the Mend webapp. A product-level admin permission is not going to be enough.
